# How to perform load testing of attachments to an Insight using Jmeter

Tags: web-applications, jmeter

I have a Web application where I can post an Insight that is a paragraph about anything and attach a file to it. I am not placing any restrictions on the file limit so I would want to really focus on performance when a user uploads a huge file.

I am using Jmeter for my performance testing and am wondering how to actually test it. The work flow is actually like

-User goes to www.foo.com
-Logs in using Username & password 
-Clicks on the Add Insight and types a text, attaches a large file to the insight and clicks   on create

I read about FTP request sampler but I am trying to run it for concurrent clients.

Am a first time user so please bear with me.

I hope you can give me a good guidance with your expertise in Jmeter

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find one of the best ways to get your feet wet is to record the user actions, following this guide:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

After you record, you'll see all the steps that happen in the background for uploading the text and file.

You'll notice on the POST HTTP request that sends the file has a checkbox on the bottom that says "include file". This is the file that gets uploaded.